# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'transaction' was called on null. Receiver: null Dart Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi so I am trying to make an app in Flutter, but am having a difficult time figuring out what is wrong. I am trying to get it to when you click a button it adds the name of this to sqflite database but whatever I try doesn't seem to work. The value equals the write thing but then I just get a null error.

This is a page where it puts the coins you're able to select in a list. It works but I am trying to add when you click on the Listtile it will add the name to the database.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:nodemarketcap/database.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
class AddCoinPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

  AddCoinPage({Key key, @required this.databaseClient}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddCoinPageState createState() => new _AddCoinPageState();
}



class _AddCoinPageState extends State<AddCoinPage> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  String coin;

   addCoin(coinname) async {
    setState(() {
      coin = coinname;
    });
    return widget.databaseClient.addCoin(coin);
  }
  // Get json result and convert it to model. Then add
  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      _userDetails.clear();
      for (Map user in responseJson) {
        _userDetails.add(UserDetails.fromJson(user));
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getUserDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Add Coin'),
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF090909),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: () {
                    controller.clear();
                    onSearchTextChanged('');
                  },),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _searchResult.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(_searchResult[i].name),
                      onTap: () {addCoin((_searchResult[i].name).toString());}
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
              },
            )
                : new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _userDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(_userDetails[index].name),
                    onTap: () {addCoin(_userDetails[index].name);}
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _userDetails.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.name.contains(text))
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}

List<UserDetails> _searchResult = [];

List<UserDetails> _userDetails = [];

final String url = 'https://nodemarketcap.com/api/api';
class UserDetails {
  final String name;

  UserDetails({this.name});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the database class folder. I only use the first class in it; the second is a more of a failed attempt and not how I wanted to do it, but I kept it in case I needed to reuse something.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class DatabaseClient  {
  Database database;

  Future create() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");

    database  = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1,
        onCreate: this._create);

  }
  Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE coins (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
            name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
                  nameb VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
                  tickerCap VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,                   
            roi DECIMAL(8, 2) NOT NULL,
            usdvalue DECIMAL(20, 6) NOT NULL,
            changep DECIMAL(6, 2) NOT NULL,
            mnCost BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            mncount BIGINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,          
            mnpriceusd DECIMAL(20, 2) NOT NULL,
            usdvol DECIMAL(30, 2) NOT NULL,
            dailyUSD DECIMAL(20, 4) NOT NULL,
            dailyBTC DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
            monthlyUSD DECIMAL(20, 4) NOT NULL,
            monthlyBTC DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,
            yearlyUSD DECIMAL(20, 4) NOT NULL,
            yearlyBTC DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL,  
            btcval DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL, 
            usdMarketCap DECIMAL(20, 2) NOT NULL,   
            btcMarketCap DECIMAL(20, 2) NOT NULL,   
            btcvol DECIMAL(20, 8) NOT NULL
            )""");
  }
  addCoin (String name) async {
    await database.transaction((txn) async {
      int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO coins(name, nameb, tickerCap, roi, usdvalue, changep, mnCost, mncount, mnpriceusd, usdvol, dailyUSD, dailyBTC, monthlyUSD, monthlyBTC, yearlyUSD, yearlyBTC, btcval, usdMarketCap, btcMarketCap, btcvol) VALUES(name, "refresh", "refresh", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)');
      print("insertedcoin: $id1");
    });
  }
  updateCoin (name, nameb, tickerCap, roi, usdvalue, changep, mnCost, mncount, mnpriceusd, usdvol, dailyUSD, dailyBTC, monthlyUSD, monthlyBTC, yearlyUSD, yearlyBTC, btcval, usdMarketCap, btcMarketCap, btcvol) async {
    int update = await database.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE coins SET nameb = ?, tickerCap = ?, roi = ?, usdvalue = ?, changep = ?, mnCost = ?, mncount = ?, mnpriceusd = ?, usdvol = ?, dailyUSD = ?, dailyBTC = ?, monthlyUSD = ?, monthlyBTC = ?, yearlyUSD = ?, yearlyBTC = ?, btcval = ?, usdMarketCap = ?, btcMarketCap = ?, btcvol = ?  WHERE name = ?',
        [nameb, tickerCap, roi, usdvalue, changep, mnCost, mncount, mnpriceusd, usdvol, dailyUSD, dailyBTC, monthlyUSD, monthlyBTC, yearlyUSD, yearlyBTC, btcval, usdMarketCap, btcMarketCap, btcvol, name]);
    print("updated: $update");
  }
  getTest () async {
    List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM coins');
    print(list);
  }
}

class Coins {
  Coins();

  int id;
  String name;
  String nameb;
  String tickerCap;
  double roi;
  double usdvalue;
  double changep;
  int mnCost;
  int mncount;
  double mnpriceusd;
  double usdvol;
  double dailyUSD;
  double dailyBTC;
  double monthlyUSD;
  double monthlyBTC;
  double yearlyUSD;
  double yearlyBTC;
  double btcval;
  double usdMarketCap;
  double btcMarketCap;
  double btcvol;

  static final columns = ["id", "name", "nameb", "tickerCap", "roi", "usdvalue", "changep", "mnCost", "mncount", "mnpriceusd", "usdvol", "dailyUSD", "dailyBTC", "monthlyUSD", "monthlyBTC", "yearlyUSD", "yearlyBTC", "btcval", "usdMarketCap", "btcMarketCap", "btcvol"];

  Map toMap() {
    Map map = {
      "name": name,
      "nameb": nameb,
      "tickerCap": tickerCap,
      "roi": roi,
      "usdvalue": usdvalue,
      "changep": changep,
      "mnCost": mnCost,
      "mncount": mncount,
      "mnpriceusd": mnpriceusd,
      "usdvol": usdvol,
      "dailyUSD": dailyUSD,
      "dailyBTC": dailyBTC,
      "monthlyUSD": monthlyUSD,
      "monthlyBTC": monthlyBTC,
      "yearlyUSD": yearlyUSD,
      "yearlyBTC": yearlyBTC,
      "btcval": btcval,
      "usdMarketCap": usdMarketCap,
      "btcMarketCap": btcMarketCap,
      "btcvol": btcvol
    };
    if (id != null) {
      map["id"] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }
  static fromMap(Map map) {
    Coins coins = new Coins();
    coins.id = map["id"];
    coins.name = map["name"];
    coins.nameb = map["nameb"];
    coins.tickerCap = map["tickerCap"];
    coins.roi = map["roi"];
    coins.usdvalue = map["usdvalue"];
    coins.changep = map["changep"];
    coins.mnCost = map["mnCost"];
    coins.mncount = map["mncount"];
    coins.mnpriceusd = map["mnpriceusd"];
    coins.usdvol = map["usdvol"];
    coins.dailyUSD = map["dailyUSD"];
    coins.dailyBTC = map["dailyBTC"];
    coins.monthlyUSD = map["monthlyUSD"];
    coins.yearlyUSD = map["yearlyUSD"];
    coins.yearlyBTC = map["yearlyBTC"];
    coins.btcval = map["btcval"];
    coins.usdMarketCap = map["usdMarketCap"];
    coins.btcMarketCap = map["btcMarketCap"];
    coins.btcvol = map["btcvol"];
    return coins;
  }
}
```

This is the error i get

```
08-18 15:06:20.845 19017-19136/com.nodemarketcap.nodemarketcap E/flutter: [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
    NoSuchMethodError: The method 'transaction' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: transaction<Null>(Closure: (Transaction) => Future<Null>)
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)
    #1      DatabaseClient.addCoin (package:nodemarketcap/database.dart:46:20)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      _AddCoinPageState.addCoin (package:nodemarketcap/add_coin_page.dart:26:34)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      _AddCoinPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:nodemarketcap/add_coin_page.dart:100:32)
    #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:494:14)
    #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:549:30)
    #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
    #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
    #8      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:123:7)
    #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
    #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147:20)
    #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
    #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
    #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
    #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
    #15     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
    #16     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)
```

So I am trying to get this to work but banging my head. I am probably doing something stupid so if someone may tell me what I did wrong and can tell me what I can improve on. :P IDK, thank you.

Comment: create() is never called :)

Comment: Oh ok :P ill look into that thank you @diegoveloper

Answer (score 0):

The error `The method 'transaction' was called on null.` points that `transaction` was called on a null method. The likely cause of this issue was from `database` being null. Make sure to initialize `database` to solve this issue.